# Any way to set minimum Cell Height in an Excel Sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Hello my question is how to set a minimum Height for Cells in an Excel Sheet? Right now it looks like: [image: Excel Sheet]

But it should look like:[image: How it should look] I tried so far to set the cell height with: `excelSheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 16.14;` and then the `excelSheet.Columns[1].Autofit()` but it gets overriden so i was hoping to find a way to set a minimum Height for the Autofit. Then i tried to google for it but nothing helpful showed up. For the cells they get merged with

```
// Merge the Cells for the summary Box
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
{
    excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[startColumn + i, 1], excelSheet.Cells[startColumn + i, 10]].Merge(Missing.Value);
}
```

and then a linebreak with `excelSheet.get_Range("A" + lineBreakAreaTop, "J" + lineBreakAreaBottom).WrapText = true;` Mabey this has something to do with it.

So any help or advise would be great an thanks for your Time. And sorry for my english.

Comment: There are tons of libraries out there that is better than the interop api.
One of these is [Closed](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). You can easily adjust the height based on contents as stated in their [documentation](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adjust%20Row%20Height%20and%20Column%20Width%20to%20Contents&referringTitle=Documentation). Maybe you could give it a try

Comment: well i am supposed to use the interop api. Sadly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simulate Min Height in Excel

To simulate a `Min Height` setting in the excel rows I wrote the following simple code and use it by the bellow instruction in my excel files:

1. Open your excel file and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> in `Excel`
2. Click on `View Code` button in the opened window to open the `Editor`

[image]

3. `Copy-Paste` the bellow codes in the `Editor`

**Codes**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Cells.Rows.AutoFit
    For rowCounter = 1 To 500
        If Rows(rowCounter & ":" & rowCounter).EntireRow.RowHeight < 15 Then
              Rows(rowCounter).EntireRow.RowHeight = 15
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

> **Note 1:** If you want to force the worksheet to apply `Rows AutoFit function` on changes too, then you can uncomment it by removing the `'` sign from beginning of its code line in the above code.
>
> **Note 2:** If the row count of the data is more than `500` in your excel file, then increse this number in the above code to an appropriate value.

4. Save it by  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in the `Editor`
5. Go back to the sheet and change any cell value and leave the cell, now you should see the result ;)